# PHP salt and hash password not matching when using in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, hash

They both values coming from database,

```
Salt: 785
Stored Hashed Password:6e8638c62ddd65ff91ee1c6650395189cee99124a8b3f2e53e542cfe7c8c1abe

$sal = 785;
$pass = $_POST['login_password'];

$hash = hash('sha256', $sal . hash('sha256', $pass));
echo $hash;

New hash created:c4170c8796a3f50e89c3e7d6c2af38f098cd83465369f9dc98e83fc4e82ea412
```

Both not matched,

Comment: Are you sure that your salt is actually '785' and not, say, ' 785' or '785 '?

Comment: Is the salt meant to be concatenated with the hash of the password and then hashed?

Comment: Yes,this is the array:

Array ( [0] => 785 [1] => 6e8638c62ddd65ff91ee1c6650395189cee99124a8b3f2e53e542cfe7c8c1abe )

Comment: I wouldn't recommend double hashing. What about the `login_password`'s case?

Comment: this is the password which i entered in my login form,